# How to get SID programmatically : Magento 2

Tags: url, session, magento2.1.5

I am working on multi store

> Store > Configuration > General > Web > Session Validation Settings >
>   Use SID on Storefront is set to "Yes" allow customer to stay logged in
>   when switching between different stores.

[image]

However I am not getting SID in my front end URL. Is there any way to get SID pragmatically and append to front end URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get get Session from **getSessionId()** Using

```
Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface\SessionManager
```

How session is appended to url you can refer to **createUrl()** in

```
Magento\Framework\Url
```

It appends throught **_prepareSessionUrl()**

```
/**
 * Check and add session id to URL
 *
 * @param string $url
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
 */
protected function _prepareSessionUrl($url)
{
    if (!$this->getUseSession()) {
        return $this;
    }
    $sessionId = $this->_session->getSessionIdForHost($url);
    if ($this->_sidResolver->getUseSessionVar() && !$sessionId) {
        $this->setQueryParam('___SID', $this->_isSecure() ? 'S' : 'U');
    } elseif ($sessionId) {
        $this->setQueryParam($this->_sidResolver->getSessionIdQueryParam($this->_session), $sessionId);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I accepted it but I can't add up vote due to my less reputation.

Comment: It is not accepted Waseem. You need to click the accept Icon.

Comment: ok clicked on accept icon...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver`. You can add it in DI and get current SID using the method `getSid`.

You can debug why your session id parameter is mised from the url inside the `Magento\Framework\Url` class in the `useSessionIdForUrl` method, where the magento checks is SID should be added to the url or not:

```
/**
 * Check and return use SID for URL
 *
 * @param bool $secure
 * @return bool
 */
public function useSessionIdForUrl($secure = false)
{
    $key = 'use_session_id_for_url_' . (int)$secure;
    if (is_null($this->getData($key))) {
        $httpHost = $this->_request->getHttpHost();
        $urlHost = parse_url($this->_getScope()->getBaseUrl(UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_LINK, $secure), PHP_URL_HOST);

        if ($httpHost != $urlHost) {
            $this->setData($key, true);
        } else {
            $this->setData($key, false);
        }
    }
    return $this->getData($key);
}
```

SID appears in a request only when you go from one host to other host.